# Why is the Privacy Act called the Privacy Act?

Tags: united-states, privacy, legal-research, foia

The American Privacy Act allows subjects to access copies of records held on them by US government agencies.

But what does it have to do with privacy?

Comment: How have you tried to answer this question yourself? If I google "The American privacy act" the first three results (all from the .gov top-level domain) state that the act relates to disclosure as well as right of access.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because **Why** the law is what it is is Off Topic. The Lawmaker said so is usually the only answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**what does it have to do with privacy?**

This can be explained by reference to the full title of the [Privacy Act 1974](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_Act_of_1974) ([as amended](https://www.justice.gov/opcl/privacy-act-1974)):

> An Act to amend title 5, United States Code, by adding a section 552a, **to safeguard individual privacy from the misuse of Federal records**, to provide that individuals be granted access to records concerning them which are maintained by Federal agencies, **to establish a Privacy Protection Study Commission**, and for other purposes. (*my emboldenment*)